# OpenBSD /dev/sd0k unexpected inconsistency - bad super block

Tags: boot, disk, openbsd, fsck

i got a big problem when i try to boot my VMware OpenBSD 5.7 i got this : [image: screenshoot]

I can see all my data making  : cat /root/mydata
they have nothing important for me into sd0k (/home)
i've try fsck etc, the problem stays
what i can do to boot ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At that prompt, press <kbd>Return</kbd> to get a root shell.

Then run

```
# fsck sd0k
```

This ought to repair the inconsistencies found.

If you have nothing important on `sd0k` and want to reformat the partition, then, as root, make sure that the filesystem that `sd0k` contains is no longer mounted, then do

```
# newfs sd0k
```

... taking *great precaution* to enter the correct device name and making sure that you know that the partition will be forever lost.

You should then recreate your home directory there and use that rather than working with your OpenBSD system as root (this is a bad idea on any Unix system).

You should also upgrade to a newer version of OpenBSD.  The current stable release is 6.1 and 6.2 is just around the corner.  Release 5.7 was released in mid 2015 and is no longer supported.

Comment: thanks, but i got always an error doing this https://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/658185err.png

Comment: @Bernardo I've updated. One does not specify `/dev`, only the device name.

Comment: yeah ! that worked, (newfs sd0k)